# HexapawnBoard class in Java

Tags: java

I have to complete 4 methods but I am having difficulty understanding them. I'm trying to complete `whitemove()`. I know that I have to iterate through the board, but I cannot totally understand how I'm supposed to do it!

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HexapawnBoard {
private static final int WHITE_PIECE = 1;
private static final int BLACK_PIECE = 2;
private static final int EMPTY = 0;

private static final int BOARD_SIZE = 3;

private int[][] board;

/**
 * Create a board position from a string of length BOARD_SIZE*BOARD_SIZE (9).
 * The first BOARD_SIZE positions in the string correspond to the black player's home
 * position. The last BOARD_SIZE positions in the string correspond ot the white player's
 * home position. So, the string "BBB   WWW" corresponds to a starting position.
 * 
 * @param pos the string encoding the position of the board
 */
public HexapawnBoard(String pos)
{
    if(pos.length() != BOARD_SIZE * BOARD_SIZE)
        throw new RuntimeException("HexapawnBoard string must be of length BOARD_SIZExBOARD_SIZE");

    board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    for(int row=0;row<BOARD_SIZE;row++)
    {
        for(int col=0;col<BOARD_SIZE;col++)
        {
            switch(pos.charAt(row*BOARD_SIZE+col))
            {
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                board[row][col] = BLACK_PIECE;
                break;
            case 'W':
            case 'w':
                board[row][col] = WHITE_PIECE;
                break;
            case ' ':
                board[row][col] = EMPTY;
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Hexapawn board pattern " + pos);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A copy constructor of HexapawnBoard
 * 
 * @param other the other instance of HexapawnBoard to copy
 */
public HexapawnBoard(HexapawnBoard other)
{
    board = new int[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    for(int i=0;i<BOARD_SIZE;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<BOARD_SIZE;j++)
            this.board[i][j] = other.board[i][j];
}


/**
 * Return a string version of the board. This uses the same format as the 
 * constructor (above)
 * 
 * @return a string representation of the board.
 */
public String toString()
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int row=0;row<BOARD_SIZE;row++)
    {
        for(int col=0;col<BOARD_SIZE;col++)
        {
            switch(board[row][col])
            {
            case BLACK_PIECE:
                sb.append('B');
                break;
            case WHITE_PIECE:
                sb.append('W');
                break;  
            case EMPTY:
                sb.append(' ');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/**
 * Determine if this board position corresponds to a winning state.
 * 
 * @return true iff black has won.
 */
public boolean blackWins()
{
    for(int col=0;col<BOARD_SIZE;col++)
        if(board[BOARD_SIZE-1][col] == BLACK_PIECE)
            return true;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Determine if this board position corresponds to a winning state
 * 
 * @return true iff white has won
 */
public boolean whiteWins()
{
    for(int col=0;col<BOARD_SIZE;col++)
        if(board[0][col] == WHITE_PIECE)
            return true;
    return false;
}

/**
 * Determine if black has a move
 * 
 * @ return truee iff black has a move
 */
public boolean blackCanMove()
{

    return false;
}

/**
 * Return a List of valid moves of white. Moves are represented as valid 
 * Hexapawn board positions. If white cannot move then the list is empty.
 * 
 * @return A list of possible next moves for white
 */
public List<HexapawnBoard> whiteMoves()
{
    return null
}

/**
 * Determine if two board positions are equal
 * @param other the other board position
 * @return true iff they are equivalent board positions
 */
public boolean equals(HexapawnBoard other)
{

    return true;
}

/**
 * Determine if two board positions are reflections of each other
 * @param other the other board position
 * @return true iff they are equivalent board positions
 */
public boolean equalsReflection(HexapawnBoard other)
{

    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: What is this code ? What is it suppose to do ? What errors do you get (if any) ?

Comment: Also if this is homework, please add the `homework` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code that you have so far seems to be correct.

Now, for the four methods that you have left, I can't really help you with the `blackCanMove()` or the `whiteMoves()` methods because I don't know what the rules for moving are in this hexapawn game. If you would explain the rules, I could help with that.

As far as the `equals()` and `equalsReflection()` methods go, you basically need to do what you did in the copy constructor, but instead of copying, do a conditional test. If two positions do not match up to what they are supposed to be, return `false`. Otherwise, once you have checked each square and they are all correct, return `true`.

As far as the `whiteMoves()` method, you need to iterate through the board and find all of the white pieces.  For each white piece, there may be a few (at most 3) valid moves.  Check each of those positions to see if they are possible.  The piece may move diagonally if there is a black piece in that spot, or it may move forward if there is no piece at all in that spot.  For each valid move, create a new `HexapawnBoard` representing what the board would look life following that move. At the end of the method, return a list of all of the `HexapawnBoard`s that you created.

Comment: @MoeAlShaiban: I cannot access that pdf because I am not a student at your school. Could you just explain the rules?

Comment: sorry for that here is a pic for all possible moves http://www.flickr.com/photos/moe0/7449939014/in/photostream

Comment: @MoeAlShaiban: I have provided some information in my answer above. It's actually a pretty simple problem. For each piece, you just have to check to see whether it can legally move into any of three possibilities, and if it can, create a new Board representing that move.